# Select and manipulate g elements of an SVG using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

How can I select all paths inside a g group by class? For example

```
<svg>  
...  
<g  
class="myClass"  
...  
<path  
...  
/>
```

in javascript, how could select all the paths inside myClass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use usual DOM methods, like `querySelector`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, ...

```js
function randHexColor() { // Be aware it can produce invalid colors
  return '#' + (Math.random()*Math.pow(2,8*3)|0).toString(16);
}
var svg = document.getElementById('svg'),
    paths = svg.querySelectorAll('.myClass > path');
for(var i=0; i<paths.length; ++i) {
  paths[i].style.fill = randHexColor();
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" height="200" width="350">  
  <g class="myClass" transform="scale(50)" fill="orange" >
    <path d="M 1,1 3,1 2,3 Z" />
    <path d="M 4,1 6,1 5,3 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this method to my specific situation, but I am getting an error that just says the function is not defined. Are you sure this method work when the svg is in an object tag geing loaded externally?

Comment: @Iatesometau You should post the code you use to load the svg.

Comment: No, they are of the same origin. Doing some more Googling, will be back in a few.

Comment: Tried to debug by alerting paths.toString() and got back  [object NodeList]. Is that meaningful?

Comment: AHA! I found a working solution.  
    paths[i].style.fill ="#xxxxxx");
instead of 
    paths[i].setAttribute('fill', "#xxxxxx");
not sure why the second way doesn't work, though.

Comment: :'c now the trouble is getting elements I have manipulated to reset. I will make a new help topic I suppose.

Comment: @Iatesometau Good point. Not sure why `setAttribute` didn't work, but using `style` is the proper way of doing it.